# bootstrap modal to appear when dropdownlist item is selected in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I want a bootstrap modal with partial view to popup when a user selects the dropdownlist item.
For each selected item the popup should refresh with new content when the user selects a different item in the dropdownlist. From the code below, I could able to make the ajax and then redirect to partial view with model values but unable to display the modal popup

Index.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedIssue, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
            <div class="col-md-9">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedIssue, Model.IssueDetails, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "IssueId" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedIssue, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


$("#IssueId").change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetActionDetails")',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: { id: $("#IssueId").val() },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modal-content').html(data);
                $('#modal-container').modal('show');
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve action details' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

The dropdown selection is making an ajax call and calling the below method in the controller

```
public ActionResult GetActionDetails(string id)
        {
            ActionDetails model = new ActionDetails();

            model.ActionTaken = "Action Taken ";
            model.AdviceGiven = "Advice Given to";
            return PartialView("ActionDetails", model);
        }
```

This is then redirecting to PartialView ActionDetails view which is below.

```
@model OnCallLogging.Models.ActionDetails

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Action Details</h3>
</div>

<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.ActionTaken, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3"})
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ActionTaken, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => Model.AdviceGiven, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-3" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.AdviceGiven, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

And in the Layout.cshtml, the following markup is written before the body closing tag.

```
<div id="modal-container" class="modal fade hidden-print" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in the script.css

```
.modal-content {
    width: 600px !important;
    margin: 30px auto !important;
}
```

When I run the code, the screen goes dim but no popup appears. When I debug I could see ajax calling the controller action and redirecting to partial view, but the popup does not appear.
Not sure what am I missing to show the popup with model properties. Could anyone please help.

Comment: Typo: `$("#IsssueId")` -> `$("#IssueId")`

Comment: Use the console to check if the modal is still hidden by something

Answer (score 0):

Since you are seeing the controller action being called while debugging, the harder part is working.  The most likely explanation for your issue is in your javascript "success:":

```
//change from this:
$('#modal-content').html(data);

//to this:
$('.modal-content').html(data);
```

You can optionally, change your `<div class="modal-content">` to `<div id="modal-content">`